# Using a Blob as a Flash object

Tags: javascript, html, flash, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a Flash object stored in a blob, however my approach using the URL returned by `URL.createObjectURL` as the `src` of the embed tag just results in the browser downloading the blob as a file.

Here's my generated HTML:

```
<object height="500" width="1000">
    <embed height="500" width="1000" src="blob:http://127.0.0.1:34721/1fa7a01c-25b7-4ad0-ba1d-1ddef61617ce"/>
</object>
```

And here's JavaScript used to generate the Blob and `object` tag:

```
var blob = new Blob(data, {
               type: 'application/x-shockwave-flash'
           });

document.body.innerHTML += '<object height="500" width="1000" ><embed height="500" width="1000" src="' + URL.createObjectURL(blob) + '"/></object>'
```

Where `data` is an array of `Uint8Array`s, each containing 256 bytes of the binary data.

The blob in question has a type of `application/x-shockwave-flash` and is identical to the original `.swf` file (I checked). The file itself works when used in place of the Object URL.

From what I have read, an Object URL pointing to a blob can be used any place a normal URL could. Are embed tags an exception to this?

Comment: This is a guess: I wonder if the embed tag may miss the mime type that it normally gets from a response header?  Try setting "type="application/x-shockwave-flash" as an attribute inside your embed tag. I don't know though, Flash isn't widely supported, I'd test across browsers to see if it's the same error.

Comment: @Radio That worked! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embed tag may miss the mime type that it normally gets from a response header. Try setting "type="application/x-shockwave-flash" as an attribute inside your embed tag.

Still, Flash isn't widely supported anymore, I'd test across browsers to see if it's the same error. You may need to add the type to the object tag in legacy browsers.